# google extension being loaded twice? Incognito is fine

Tags: google-chrome-extension

for some reason my injected.js is being loaded twice and the strange thing is that they are different. One is older than another. Everythnig was wokring fine untill yesterday. Code wasn't changed at all.

https://prnt.sc/10p8w9s

Clearing cache and everything for that specific site when extension is available is not working. How can I fix that?

Comment: The question lacks [MCVE](/help/mcve) but the only explanation is `all_frames` was specified in the content script declaration (in manifest.json) or `allFrames` in executeScript's parameters.

Comment: The problem is it wasn't specified. It was working untill it wasnt :P Nothing changed in the code.

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Ok, ill do that and get back with the results.

Comment: Im soo stupid.. It was loading twice and used different code because I had 2 different version (manifest) working at the same time -.-